# how to wrap content a custom view in Swift

Tags: swift, xib

I have created a xib file which contains some subviews. I set the appreciate  width and height for the subviews.

there is class which inherited `UIView`. This class name is `CustomUIView`. Then I set This class as the file owner of that xib file.

Now I want to add this xib file to a view controller in storyboard. so I add a UIView and set its class to `CustomUIView`.
But I have to set width and height for this view. I set leading and top constraint. but I want the height and width of it be set based on the height and width of the subviews.
How should I do it

Comment: Set leading and trailing constraint to determine the width. Set top and bottom constraint to determine the height. Please read about Autolayout

Comment: @user1046037 Thanks. but I set these in the subviews of the custom view and I don't want to set them again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set width and height anchors for the view , if you already set it inside the xib for every element

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let v = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("hhhh", owner: self, options: nil))?[0] as! hhhh;

    view.addSubview(v)

    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.topAnchor,constant:30).isActive = true

    v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.leadingAnchor,constant:30).isActive = true


}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Exactly. I needed it to do so. but when I set tap gesture recognizer, only when I assign width and height it works. otherwise it doesn't work. and auto layout shows error that it needs width and height for that view